# Convert a OSM file to geojson file using osmtogeosjon in a subprocess command line within Python

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, geojson

My goals is to convert an .osm file to a .geojson file. 
I want to automate the process within a python script,

I somehow can't figure it out why this script won't work:

```
import subproces

subprocess.check_output("osmtogeojson data.osm > data2.geojson", 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True)
```

This code returns:

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'osmtogeojson data.osm > data2.geojson' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

did I type something wrong? When I run the same command in cmd (in the correct path of the file (users/me/folder)) it works.

edit: I have used the package from https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson which is based on node.js

Comment: Try `p = subprocess.Popen([LIST, OF, ARGUMENTS ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and `p.communicate`

Comment: `[ "osmtogeojson", "data.osm", ">", "data2.geojson"]`

Comment: I tried to do this:
`p = subprocess.Popen(["osmtogeojson", "data.osm", ">", "data2.geojson"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True) `. After I used `p.communicate()` this returns:
(b'', None)

if I loko at the file data2.geojson, I see that it's edited but it's empty

Comment: Sounds like it's erroring out when running from the context of Python. What do you get with `os.system()`?

Comment: it returns: TypeError: system() missing required argument 'command' (pos 1)

Comment: Have you tried specifying a fully qualified path to `osmtogeojson`?